# Converting a factor into a string column in a dataset

Tags: r, string, converters, factors

I am trying to plot the Id column with some other variables which I have managed to do with geom_col but when my plot is retrieved I can see that R is taking the column "Id" as a factor or number and I am not getting the results I am looking for, here the graph:

[image]

How can I convert the column into a string so that it actually allow me to plot all the users that participated in the survey which are 33? Here is where I'm coming from:

```r
activity_distance <- 
  merged_activity_calories %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarise(
    mean_activity_distance= mean(VeryActiveDistance), 
    mean_ma_distance= mean(ModeratelyActiveDistance), 
    mean_la_distance= mean(LightActiveDistance), 
    mean_sa_distance= mean(SedentaryActiveDistance)
  )

ggplot(data= activity_distance) + 
  geom_col(mapping= aes(x=Id , y= mean_activity_distance))
```

Comment: Best if you can post an example of your input data.. for example `dput(head(merged_activity_calories))`...

Comment: Add the following after `summary(...)` in order to make `Id` a character vector: `%>% mutate(Id = as.character(Id))`. I am not sure, however, if that solves your issue with the presentation of the x-axis in your plot.

Comment: Thank you very much @benimwolfspelz it has helped a lot! I have now some idea as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert ID into a factor.

```
library(ggplot)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1232121321321321,123213213213,123213213213213),
                 y = c(123,234,22.4))
ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = (id), y = y))
ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = factor(id), y = y))
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is something that I thought of trying but that would have taken way too long to accomplish so I was trying to look for a command that would help me do it from the dataset that I was given but I appreciate your time and knowledge.